# copied a working jQuery form to another location but only the original works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, submit

I've copied a working jQuery form from one page to another, the original works as intended but the duplicate does not.

The original works like so:
So i have an onclick function attached to an image which opens up a confirmation modal window with an "OK" button (aka) my submit button, pressing this submits a post function, closing the window and creating a post on another page (the main page).

I've copied this working form to my main page so users wouldn't have to travel to the above mentioned page to accomplish this task. However, upon clicking the "OK" button on the duplicated form, it closes the window and refreshes the page, but the post function does not seem to be triggering.

The code is below:

```
<script>
            jQuery(function (){
                jQuery('#form-bumb .button-waiting, #form-bumb .waiting-updated').hide();
                jQuery('#form-bumb').submit(function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //product_id
                    jQuery('#form-bumb .waiting-updated').hide();
                    jQuery('#form-bumb .button-waiting').show();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
                        type : 'post',
                        data : {
                            action : 'product_bump',
                            product_id : <?php echo $product_id; ?>
                        },
                        success : function( response ) {
                            jQuery('#form-bumb .button-waiting').hide();
                            jQuery('#form-bumb .waiting-updated').show();
                            jQuery('#form-bumb button[type=submit]').hide();

                            remaining_bump = jQuery('.products-total-wrap #products-total-bumps').text();
                            if (remaining_bump > 0){
                                remaining_bump = parseInt(remaining_bump) - 1;
                                jQuery('.products-total-wrap #products-total-bumps').text(remaining_bump);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });

                jQuery('#modal_product_message_confirmation h4.modal-title').html('Bump Confirmation '+
                            '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>'+
                            '/assets_consumer/assets/img/bump-icon.png" width="20" />');
            });
            </script>
```

I have no idea what the problem is, if anyone would be so kind to point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, how do you debug it? Check console for error(s)

Comment: I see you're using PHP data inside the JS, is this data available to this page as well - `<?php echo $product_id; ?>`? is `the_ajax_script` available?

Comment: I've checked console on inspect element and nothing seems to be showing. As mentioned this code works perfectly fine on one page. All i did was add the necessary php include lines to another page to make the form accessible from there but it does not trigger

Comment: Good question, ill look into it now @Jamesonthedog

Comment: Im guessing the php is available to the new page because upon inspecting the script for said product on the new page the php call returns the correct data @Jamesonthedog

Comment: and `the_ajax_script` as well?

Comment: yes it is loaded on the new page @Jamesonthedog

Comment: okay, maybe this - you write that after button is pressed it closes the window and refreshes the page, should this be happening? since you `preventDefault` on the event, and I don't see anything like that in your code

Comment: No that shouldnt be happening, when i submit it from the original modal window, a tick box appears and the window remains open which is as intended. @Jamesonthedog

Comment: now we're getting somewhere - it looks like your problem is probably here: `jQuery('#form-bumb').submit(function (e){ e.preventDefault();.....` is the id (`form-bumb`) correct?

Comment: I havent had to adjust the code at all. the code is written in a php file and all ive done is included that file onto this new page along with all the other necessary files using php include - but yes the id is correct @Jamesonthedog

Comment: look, something isn't defined properly - it could be the HTML markup, it could be jQuery (not defined) or it could be diffrent instances (frames) bottom line is - `e.preventDefault()` is not called, and that's where I'd focus. I can't see your entire page so I don't know what else to tell you, maybe make a fiddle or something?

Comment: you know what, last idea - is it possible the form is created dynamically in this page? so at the time you execute `jQuery('#form-bumb').submit(....` it doesn't exist yet? try `$(document).on('submit','#form-bumb',function(e){...`

Comment: you sir, are an absolute LEGEND! copied your code and it works like a charm. a HUGE thankyou for saving my brain cells. This has been bugging me for some time now. Thanks again! @Jamesonthedog

Comment: No problem, the community is here to help :) i'll post as answer so you can mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps your form is generated dynamically and `#form-bumb` doesn't exist at time of running `jQuery('#form-bumb').submit(function (e){....})`

you should try instead

```
$(document).on('submit','#form-bumb',function(e){....})
```

which will also work on the form if it's dynamically created